# Nvidia Settings not saving in ubuntu 20.04 after reboot

Tags: 20.04, nvidia-settings

So I have two monitors secondary one  of which I rotate to the left and use nvidia settings but does not save those settings after reboot I have tried saving the x config file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` both by merging and not merging as well as using root access to no avail.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I've tried using sudo, changing xorg.conf permissions, changing display port, etc. None worked. Bug tracker -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1874217

Comment: The nvidia-settings tool has an option to save configs. Make sure you do it, and if a config file is saved in the home folder, move it.

Comment: Same problem. A real Ubuntu-tier issue, highly embarrassing.

Comment: Same problem - "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" is set but doesn't seem to happen on reboot (judging by indicator light) until I reopen the settings menu .

Answer (score 2):

adding x permission to `/usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-polkit` fixed the issue for me

```
sudo chmod u+x /usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-polkit
```